# Python, cannot import from top level __init__.py

Tags: python, import, circular-dependency

Here's my current folder structure

```
.
├── api
│   ├── api_routes.py
│   └── sql
│       └── models.py  # import db into this file
├── application
│   └── __init__.py    # db here
└── wsgi.py
```

In `__init__.py` there's a variable `db` (Flask-SQLAlchemy instance) and a function `create_app`, all of which are successfully imported into `wsgi.py` using this line:

```py
from application import create_app
```

I used the same line to import `db` into `models.py`, to no avail. What can I do now? I have no idea where to start. One SO post suggests that maybe there's a circular import involved, however, I can't find it in my code. I also tried to import with these lines without success:

```py
from . import create_app
from .application import create_app
from ..application import create_app
```

Edit: after 1 week turning a way from the problem, I found the line that causes it all. The problem was indeed circular dependency. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Have you tried to put an `__init__.py` into your sql folder? (can be empty)

Comment: @TheFool I haven't. I do add `__init__.py` but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Hey, I see you figured it out. If you don't mind writing a small summary as answer and accepting it, it would be very helpful for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

There are few tricks to handle such imports,

1) Mark the "application" folder as the "Sources Root", and then I think it should work (marking folder as sources root is relatively easy when using pycharm so I suggest you to use pycharm for this and for many more tricks with python)

2) trick number to is to add the path to the directory you want to import from to sys.path, do something like

```
import sys
sys.path = ['/path/to/your/folder'] + sys.path
...
other code
```

and then importing should work.

I hope this will help (: